Definition of semantics of coinductive type
It is relatively easy to construct an object in set/class theory which has properties of any of the following: dependent sum, dependent product,  W-types.
E.g. Dependent sum of a family F is just the composition $(E^{-1}\ $o$\  F)$. (it depends slightly on definitions, but this is the idea)
Fix some family B. (let's say it is a class-function, or even just function)
But how to obtain an object which will represent M(x:A)B(x)?
(i.e. I am trying to implement coinductive types)
It was easy to implement inductive types, W(x:A)B(x) with a recursive definition of "stages" followed by set-theoretic union. But how to implement coinductive types M(x:A)B(x) ? How to mathematically define an object which will be a set-theoretic semantic of "M(x:A)B(x)"?
(related to this question : Definition of M-type in type theory )
very related to
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4919803/way-of-defining-families-of-proper-classes-in-class-theory


What do you mean by "object" and "represent"? If you are talking about underlying realizers (in some computational model), you could look at the proof that realizability models interpret $M$-types as final coalgebras for polynomial functors. I can't tell whether you'd like to see how $M$-types are constructed in set theory, or implemented as datastructures.

Would it suffice to answer the question with: the $W$-type for a family $B : A \to \mathsf{Type}$ consists of well-founded trees with $A$-labeled nodes and branching types~$B$, while the corresponding $M$-type consists of all such trees (not necessarily well-founded)?

@AndrejBauer  I understand how it should look like, but defining it is a bit elusive.  How to define a class of such structures as a term anywhere in ZFC/NBG/MK ? For me answer is anything "It is a class of .... .  (R is infinite tree) :<-> (... forall p in R: ...) . "

@AndrejBauer I have posted an implementation in Coq as an answer to this question. I think I understand that element of w type is just arbitrary collection of branches = functions to sigma type with at most countable domains, just want to double-check that understanding is correct.

This is my attempt to define M-types in Coq.
Inductive sigma (A:Type) (F:A->Type) : Type :=
 sigma_intro : forall (a : A), (F a) -> (sigma A F)  
.

Require Import List.


(* countable collection of something *)
Inductive Cou (X:Type) : Type :=
  fin : (list X) -> Cou X
| inf : (nat -> X) -> Cou X.

Definition M (A:Type) (F:A->Type) : Type 
  := sigma Type (fun Q => sigma Q (fun _ => Cou (sigma A F))).

(* It may not be enough: requires equal beginnings *)

Set-theoretically it will be something like
$$
MF := \mathcal{P}\{f:D \to\Sigma F| (D\in\omega)\lor(D=\omega)\}
$$
$$
= \mathcal{P}\{f|\exists D: (f:D \to \Sigma F) \land ( (D\in\omega)\lor(D=\omega))\}
$$
(D is a variable bound by notation for class-collection)
Or should the values of the initial segments of the branches with equal initial labels coincide? Then it is necessary to require coinciding initial labels to have coinciding initial values
$$
MF := \{Q\in\mathcal{P}\{f:D \to\Sigma F| (D\in\omega)\lor(D=\omega)\} | \forall f,g\in Q: \forall \mbox{i initial segment of }\omega: ((pr_1 \circ f)\restriction i)=((pr_1 \circ g) \restriction i) \longrightarrow f \restriction i =  g \restriction i\}
$$
